# Drupal Error log services

Tags: views, services

Can I create views for error logs, or directly expose them to services? How can I maintain my own error logs and expose them in services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I create views for error logs?

Yep, you can create Views for pretty much any type of data. There are a couple of existing modules that already do this:

- [Views Watchdog](https://drupal.org/project/views_watchdog)
- [Better Watchdog UI](https://drupal.org/project/better_watchdog_ui)

Or you could of course write your own.

To expose Views as services, you can use the [Services Views](https://drupal.org/project/services_views) module, or, again, you can write your own resources for the [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) module if it doesn't do exactly what you want.